# My setBackgroundColor is Always Different from photoshop

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicolor

My designers asks me to show a `UIView` with a Photoshop's RGB of 125, 178, 60. So I set the color as in the code below:

```
+ (UIColor *) okThronColor {

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)(125.0/255.0)
                           green:(CGFloat)(178.0/255.0)
                            blue:(CGFloat)(60.0/255.0) 
                           alpha:1];

}
```

Photoshop says me that the color is:
[image]

but the color on iphone is:

[image]

the problem cames with ALL the colors, every time. Why?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://cl.ly/image/3b3F38333J1W

Comment: Maybe the control you're using manipulates the color?

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting `[UIColor greenColor]` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 7 (and above) the navigation bar is translucent, and the color is affected by whatever lays behind it.

Try setting the `translucent` property to `NO`.

See the UINavigationBar [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this comes down to colour profiles. If you are using Photoshop, if I remember correctly this is defaulted to a colour profile that is best suited to photo's. Most dynamic range etc. Whereas the system will use as low a colour profile as possible because it is less of a memory footprint.

This article [here](http://inaka.net/blog/2014/09/05/getting-the-right-colors-in-your-ios-app/), suggests some methods to get around it to get the correct RGB values for iOS, with a bit more of an insight into why this is probably happening.